# How to open all URL inside WebView not in external browser?

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I am new to React native and I am trying to open my `webpages(page1,page2)` inside `webview` using react native, and my component's `webview` in the below example.

Here `page1` contains `button` on clicking that `button`, `page2` is opening in `child window` in external browser.

Can somebody please tell me how to open **page2** inside the `webview`, so that the user can get a good experience?

Example: Component 1

```
{
<WebView
                    scalesPageToFit
                    startInLoadingState={true}
                    renderLoading={() => { return <Loading/> }}
                    **source={{uri:"url to page1"}}**
                    onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={request => {
                     return request.url.startsWith(domain);
                    }}
                    style={styles.web}
                    javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
                    javaScriptEnabled={true}
                    originWhitelist={[domain+"*"]}
                />
}
```

I found the below solution but was not able to implement it in my scenario.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6886

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, this happened because of the latest `react-native-webview` version.

`setSupportMultipleWindows={true}` becomes true and in my case, it should be `false`.